# why is google font showing up 2 different ways

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts

I've been trying to get this Syncopate google font to render correctly on a site but it keeps showing up differently than the example on the site. Then after some digging I found the font page for it and there's something weird. The characters at the top are slightly different than the examples below:

[image]

notice the letter 'L' for example - and compare with the example below:

[image]

the example shows a rounded angle on the letter L whereas the characters above show a more angular L. I personally want the more rounded look but when I import the font:

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro|PT+Sans+Narrow|Syncopate:400,700');`

and then I use it on my element
`font-family: 'Syncopate', sans-serif;`

I get the more angular look. I guess that's to be expected, but is there a way to get the rounded look or is that possibly just an outdated example? Here's the page for the google font: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Syncopate. I'm asking in case I'm doing this wrong - I did see on a google thread that you can use 'Syncopate-Regular' to get the correct look, but that didnt work - is there some other way to use the font to get the right look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font **itself** uses an angular L for the uppercase `L`, and a more rounded L for the lowercase `l`.

If you really want to have rounded Ls in an uppercase word, you could simply substitute the target L for a lowercase L instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I just figured this out - looks like the rounded letters are lower case letters whereas the more angular letters are uppercase. Looking at the example characters again, looks like theres 2 rows, 1 for uppercase and 1 for lowercase